# Two Javascript Functions, Second One Works Only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two javascript functions, the first saves a draft from a text area and the second is a text editor plugin. If I load them both together, only the second one will show, but they work fine individually - just not together, unfortunately. I will place the two functions below, please let me know if you see a fix with these two; I can display the external plugin JS if necessary but it's rather large. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

To add, the both use the same jQuery version.

```
#1:

$(function() {
    setInterval(function (){
        var body = $("#body").val(); 
        var title = $("#title").val();
        var forum = $("#forum_id").val();

        DATA = "mid=" + <?php echo $mid ?> + "&body=" + body + "&title=" + title + "&forum=" + forum + "&draft_id=" + <?php echo $draft_id ?>;

        if (body.length > 0) 
        { 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "inc/save_draft.php",
                data: DATA,
                cache: false,
                success: function(){
                    $("#timestamp").show().html("Saved as a draft!");
                }
            });
        }
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#timestamp").hide();
        }, 500);// 15 seconds
    }, 1000);// 1 minute
});


#2:

$(function() {
    $("textarea").sceditor({
        plugins: 'bbcode'
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you include jQuery twice? I've seen some who do, because both plugins require jQuery. That means that at the second time, the `jQuery` object will be overwritten, and you'll lose any plugins that was attached to it.

Comment: Nope, only one. I've also checked in to this... have done TONS of Google searching to try and fix this. Thank you for asking. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your `sceditor` plugin turns the textarea into an editable iframe, and that `$("#body").val()` will yield an empty string because its value is not populated by the editor until form submit.

You need to update your first plugin so that it does not fetch `$('#body').val()`, but rather `$('#body').sceditor('instance').val()`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6EQHA/). Try changing the content in that textarea, and then using the two different methods of retreiving the changed content. Only the latter will work.

Comment: Wow, that worked! Thank you so so so so much David! You are a Godsend. <333